# scrollRectToVisible has no effect after the frame has been set to visible

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am trying to scroll a JPanel that is in a scrollPane to a given y value whenever a certain action is executed. However this line of code does not work in the method:

`CurtainCall.cuePanel.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0,250,1,1));`

I have found that if I execute this line before I call setVisible(true) in the constructor of my frame it works, however anywhere else in the code after this line it does not do anything. Any thoughts or suggestions on what I am doing wrong or how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: At a guess I would say the component you're trying to change is not the one on the screen

Comment: Try "invokeLater" it after the screen is visible.

Comment: Works opposite for me. That is on only scrolls after the frame is visible. This is because components don't have a size until the frame has been packed or made visible. So I can't duplicate your problem. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.